# WatchKit and UIAlertView / UIAlertController popup

Tags: ios, watchkit

In my WatchKit app, when the user first launches it, I would like to present to them a helpful message alert that tells them how the app works, e.g. what the buttons do, etc.

Is there something similar to UIAlertView / UIAlertController that I can call in a WatchKit app? I couldn't find an answer on this topic which may very well mean that it's not possible.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

(New in watchOS 2.0)

```
 WKAlertAction *act = [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:WKAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(void){
        NSLog(@"ALERT YES ");
    }];

 NSArray *testing = @[act];

[self presentAlertControllerWithTitle:@"Voila" message:@"This is Watch OS 2 !" preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert actions:testing];
```

SWIFT

```
func showPopup(){

    let h0 = { print("ok")}

    let action1 = WKAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .default, handler:h0)
    let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: .destructive) {}
    let action3 = WKAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {}

    presentAlert(withTitle: "Voila", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet, actions: [action1,action2,action3])

}
```

Comment: works perfectly for me, even with one button. just remember to also adjust the actions array provided to `presentAlertControllerWithTitle`

Answer (score 12):

i will add the swift4 result that work for me while using

## WKAlertAction

## watchOS 4.0

## Swift 4

```
        let action1 = WKAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style:.cancel) {
            print("cancel action")
        }
        
        let action2 = WKAlertAction.init(title: "default", style:.default) {
            print("default action")
        }
        
        let action3 = WKAlertAction.init(title: "destructive", style:.destructive) {
            print("destructive action")
        }
        
        presentAlert(withTitle: "Alert Title", message: "message is here", preferredStyle:.actionSheet, actions: [action1,action2,action3])
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, after upgrading to watchOS 2, you can present an alert view using presentAlertController of WKInterfaceController.

See [the official documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentAlertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle:actions:).

Answer (score 3):

```
   let h0 = { print("h0 action")}
   let h1 = { print("h1 action")}

   let action1 = WKAlertAction(title: "h0 action", style: .default, handler:h0)
   let action2 = WKAlertAction(title: "h1 action", style: .default, handler:h0)

   self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Title", message: "a message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet, actions: [action1, action2])
```

Code in Swift 3

Answer (score 2):

There is no such class for alerts. However you can modally present "WKInterfaceController" with the information in "WKInterfaceLabel" and one "WKInterfaceButton".

Comment: Sad, apple just made our lives more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, you can not do this. But you can of course have a modal page-based hierarchy with screenshots of how the app is working if it is the first time that the app is launched. I am doing so in my app! :)

Comment: Can you add code and screenshot of how you are doing this modally in storyboard?  There is only one main view controller in watchkit and how can you redirect a user to some other place and then never show that page again? I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I could make one more suggestion: Create a separate group for your "alert" in your initial interface controller and show/hide it as needed.

Comment: Not sure that's possible, given you can't overlap elements so you'll have to hide the main UI and it'll be very hacky (abrupt / no animation etc). Instead, showing a modal controller may be a better option if that's possible.